# Replicate Python requests.post in R using httr POST

Tags: python, r, json, post, httr

I am trying to adapt my HTTP request from running it in Python to R. This is the post request in Python:

```
import requests
import json
r = requests.post("https://feed-dev.ihsmarkit.com/apikey",
 data={'username': 'markit/resellers/API_OPS/accounts/demo.dv', 'password':
 'Example@N6'})
print("POST /apikey", r.status_code, r.reason)

apikey = r.text
print(apikey)
```

I did some research and found the httr package in R is best for dealing with API related requests. However I tried to use the POST() function in a few attempts but got the same error 400 ("MISSING_PARAMETER": Parameter username not provided.") responses. Here are a few attempts I used:

```
#attempt 1
response <- POST(url = "https://feed-dev.ihsmarkit.com/apikey",
                 add_headers(.headers = c("Content-Type"="application/x-www-form-urlencoded")),
                 authenticate('markit/resellers/API_OPS/accounts/demo.dv', 'Example@N6')
)

#attempt 2
request_body <- data.frame(
  username = 'markit/resellers/API_OPS/accounts/demo.dv',
  password = 'Example@N6'
)

request_body_json <- toJSON(list(data = request_body), auto_unbox = TRUE)

POST(url = "https://feed-dev.ihsmarkit.com/apikey",
     add_headers(.headers = c("Content-Type"="application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Accept"="application/json"),
                 body = request_body_json))


#attempt 3
result <- POST(url = "https://feed-dev.ihsmarkit.com/apikey",
               add_headers(.headers = c("Content-Type"="application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Accept"="application/json")),
               body = '{"data":{"username":"markit/resellers/API_OPS/accounts/demo.dv", "password":"Example@N6}}',
               encode = 'raw')
```

Do you know how should I properly convert my request?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
response <- POST(url = "https://feed-dev.ihsmarkit.com/apikey",
                 encode = "form",
                 body= list(
                    username ='markit/resellers/API_OPS/accounts/demo.dv', 
                    password = 'Example@N6')
)
```

Just pass your data as a list and the POST will take care of formatting it as form data when you choose `encode="form"`. Your python code doesn't seem to use JSON at all. You just have literal dictionary values where you are storing your data. Only use `authenticate()` when the HTTP endpoint requires basic HTTP authentication. For endpoints that require a username/password in the body of the message, that's not how basic HTTP authentication works.

Comment: Thank you, this works! And thanks for the explanation on why the other methods didn't work.